# Regular Expression for Number+Letter combinations in Bigquery

Tags: sql, regex, nlp, google-bigquery

I am attempting to extract 2A, 6B, 8, 9A, 33, 65c, 84 from the sequence below.

Logically this seems to require any number [0-9] attached to a single letter before either a comma or whitespace.

```
2A, Beech Avenue 
Flat 6B Earl's Court Drive 
8 Ripley Drive 
9A, Grosvenor Park Way, Thirsk 
33, Dover Priory 
Block 65c,Earl's Avenue 
84, Wayfair Drive
```

This is as far as I have got with code that works to extract numbers but single letters and spaces are proving extremely challenging:

```
REGEXP_REPLACE('[^0-9]', '') FROM list
```

Comment: Extract or remove? Please show the desired results

Comment: I am looking to extract the following list:

2A,
6B,
8,
9A,
33,
65c,
84

Comment: I cannot fathom why this would be downvoted or why someone would vote to close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method is a combination of `regexp_extract()` and `regexp_replace()`:

```
 select str,
       REGEXP_REPLACE(regexp_extract(str, r'^[0-9]+[A-Za-z]?[\W]|[\W][0-9]+[A-Za-z]?$|[\W][0-9]+[A-Za-z]?[\W]'), r'[\W]', '')
from (select '2A, Beech Avenue' as str union all
      select 'Flat 6B Earl\'s Court Drive' as str union all
      select '8 Ripley Drive' as str union all
      select '9A, Grosvenor Park Way, Thirsk' union all
      select '33, Dover Priory' as str union all
      select 'Block 65c,Earl\'s Avenue' as str union all
      select '84, Wayfair Drive'
     ) x
```

Comment: Thank you Gordon, I think this accidentally catches the commas and also misses the lower cases such as 65c?

Comment: @JonathanFrancis . . . The `regexp_replace()` fixes the issue with the commas (and other word delimiters).  I fixed the logic to get more general numbers.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, I'm still having an issue on "65c" (due to the lower case c) - any ideas?

Comment: @JonathanFrancis . . . I adjusted the answer.